# Webpack, css-loader config within webpack config object

Tags: webpack

I saw some people write `css-loader` config like this:

```
module: {
   loaders: [...]
},
cssLoader: {
    modules: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    localIdentName: '[path][name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
},
plugins: [...]
```

I try this way to set my `css-loader` config. But it seems not to work.
Is this correct? By the way, I know the `querystring` and `query` field to set `css-loader` config.

Comment: Global config like that won't work in webpack 2 (not supported by the schema). There you can use `webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin` to some effect, though.

Comment: Thanks for anwser. you mean `cssLoader` is used by `webpack2`? I use `webpack1.x`.

Comment: I don't know where that `cssLoader` comes from. I would need some actual code to tell any better.

Comment: I saw a article write like this. I have no idea.

Comment: Can you link to the article? Maybe they are using something custom there.